# Was there a history of segmented solid rockets prior to the Shuttle?

Tags: history, solid-fuel

The Shuttle famously (perhaps [infamously](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20126/26446)) had its solid rocket boosters built in segments, which were [transported](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32630/26446) to KSC and then joined together.  The [SLS](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13986/26446) will similarly have segmented SRBs.

**Were *segmented* solid rockets used before the Shuttle?**  If so, which was the first one?

Note that I am not asking about solid rockets in general, just segmented ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the [UA120x series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UA120) used on the Titan launchers starting with the [Titan IIIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_IIIC) in 1965 were segmented -- starting with the UA1205 5-segment booster, and being extended to 6-segment and 7-segment boosters.

As far as I know that was the first segmented booster used on an orbital launcher; I'm sure there were smaller scale experimental segmented boosters prior to that.